# Where to handle Exceptions - in Library or User Code

Tags: python, exception

I'm working on a Library to handle interaction with an API.
Later on I will use it to create some tools.

Now I'm wondering where to 'really' handle the exceptions.

1. Should the Library handle the exception and only return for example error codes like '{"error": "URL not found"}'
2. Pass the exception to the user code and let it be handled here

Below some examples I came up/used so far

**Example**

```
import urllib2

class Request:
    def send(self, url):
        try:
            req = urllib2.Request(url)
            request = urllib2.urlopen(req)
            response = request.read()
            return response
        except urllib2.URLError as ue:
            return 'URL not found'

request = Request()
print request.send('https://not-a-real-url-.com')
```

**Printed Exception**
    URL not found

But I could also return the URLError

```
<urlopen error [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known>
```

Or raise the error to let the user code handle is

```
try:
    print request.send('https://not-a-real-url-.com')
except urllib2.URLError as ue:
    print 'error'
```

Since I'm creating the Library and the Code I'm free to handle it what I think is best but if I want to share the Library I want to have the best error exception so the user is not facing huge problems and has to debug it.

I didn't saw any question that was really like mine so I hope this is not a duplicate.

Thanks you for your input!
Michael

Comment: I think you should print some custom error message that what might cause this error and after that raise the same exception. This way, users will have better exposure to exceptions and that will help them in debugging.

Comment: @HassanMehmood good point for the error message, this is something I normally do just missed to put it in here. So you would let the parent code handle the exception? Why?

Answer (score 0):

i would keep it on your end and add a blanket exception that prints traceback:

```
import urllib2

class Request:
    def send(self, url):
        try:
            req = urllib2.Request(url)
            request = urllib2.urlopen(req)
            response = request.read()
            return response
        except urllib2.URLError:
            return 'URL not found'
        except Exception as e:
            return 'Error: '+e

request = Request()
print request.send('https://not-a-real-url-.com')
```

Comment: So cover most common exceptions the method could face, add a blanket exception to cover everything else.. sounds good. So you suggest to complete handle it in the Library and never pass the exception to the parent code, right?

Comment: That is how I would do it